# where is my _rev field in elasticsearch index from couchdb

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb, logstash

How can I keep _rev field from my couchdb documents in elasticsearch indices. I am using logstash to add data to ES from couchdb.
In my logstash.config file, I only have input and output sections.

Here is the input section:

```
    couchdb_changes {
    db => "users"
    sequence_path => "seq_files\users_couchdb_seq"
    tags => ["users"]
    }
```

here is the output section:

```
    if "users" in [tags] {
       elasticsearch { 
        document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
        index => "users_index"
        hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
    }
```

I can see _id and rest of the fields from my couchdb database under _source field of my elasticsearch index (_id in elasticsearch is appearing as 'id') but _rev field is missing (and there is no equivalent of that in my ES index). How can I port _rev field to ES as well. Do I need to add some sort of filter for that or do I need to change something in logstash couchdb plugin? Prompt help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: its weird that no one except me got this problem.. im still stuck with this problem any help will be appreciated. Thx! –

Answer (score 1):

In your input.couchdb_changes configuration, you must add this:

```
keep_revision => true
```

[Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-couchdb_changes.html#plugins-inputs-couchdb_changes-keep_revision)